# How to match data between second occurrence of first marker and second marker with REGEX?

Tags: python, regex

**Data:**

```
<CPSs item="1">
      <CKS item="1">
        <Name item="1">join.jciie.tab</Name>
        <Address item="1">
          <DNSname item="1">join.jciie.tab</DNSname>
          <Address item="1">30.49.54.147</Address>
          <Priority item="1">65036</Priority>
          <Status item="1">Active</Status>
          <Port item="1">403</Port>
        </Address>
      </CKS>
</CPSs>
```

I want to get data between `<Address item="1">` and `</Address>`. Result I want is **30.49.54.147**, but not **`<DNSname item="1">join.jciie.tab</DNSname> <Address item="1">30.49.54.147`**.

I tried the code below, but it didn't work.

```
    import re
    address_pattern = r'<Address item="1">(.*?)</Address>'
    cks_config = re.search(address_pattern, data).group(1)
    print(cks_config)
```

How can I accomplish this ?

Comment: Regular expressions are not the best tool to parse XML. Python has `ElementTree` for that purpose built-in, but there are also great external solutions like e.g. `BeautifulSoup` that will give you less tears than regexs.

Comment: As a general comment: since you're getting information from xml, you might consider using an xml parser instead of regex.

Comment: Your code actually works for me. What is the problem you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<DNSname item="1">join.jciie.tab</DNSname> <Address item="1">30.49.54.147
```

Your code apparently catched first (outer) `Address` opening tag and last (inner) `Address` closing tag. If you are sure it will always hold IP address in decimal form, you might try using

```
address_pattern = r'<Address item="1">([\.\d]+)</Address>'
```

Explanation: look for such `Address` tag that it contain solely digits (`\d`) and dots (`\.`)